# How to remove a sequence?

Tags: mariadb

Under `mariadb-10.3.7` on an InnoDB engine, I'm trying to have the following structure:

```
drop sequence if exists user_account_id_seq;
create sequence user_account_id_seq start with 1 increment by 10;
drop table if exists user_account;
create table user_account (
  -- id bigint(20) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  id bigint(20) unsigned not null default (next value for user_account_id_seq),
  version int(10) unsigned not null,
  created_on datetime,
  updated_on datetime,
  firstname varchar(255) not null,
  lastname varchar(255) not null,
  password varchar(100),
  password_salt varchar(50),
  readable_password varchar(50),
  email varchar(50) not null,
  confirmed_email bit(1) not null check (confirmed_email in (0, 1)),
  work_phone varchar(20),
  unique key email (email),
  primary key (id)
);
```

But it doesn't want to remove a sequence:

```
--------------
drop sequence if exists user_account_id_seq
--------------

--------------
commit
--------------

--------------
create sequence user_account_id_seq start with 1 increment by 10
--------------

ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 4: Table '`useraccount`.`user_account_id_seq`' already exists
+ /usr/bin/mariadb/install/bin/mysql useraccount --protocol=tcp -h mysql -P 3306 -u root -v
--------------
```

I then manually tried these commands to show how puzzling this message is:

```
MariaDB [useraccount]> create sequence user_account_id_seq start with 1 increment by 10;
ERROR 1813 (HY000): Tablespace for table '`useraccount`.`user_account_id_seq`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT
MariaDB [useraccount]> alter table `useraccount`.`user_account_id_seq` discard tablespace; 
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'useraccount.user_account_id_seq' doesn't exist
```

Comment: Can you post the CREATE TABLE statement also and some example data? Ideally make a [SQL fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) where you can repeat the issue..

Comment: "Notes DROP SEQUENCE only removes sequences, not tables. However, **DROP TABLE can remove both sequences and tables**" source https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/drop-sequence/

Comment: I added the table creation statement. I tried to use the SQL fiddle but it doesn't offer any MariaDB version and so the sequence keyword was not accepted.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Your comment about the `drop table <sequence name>` is a solution, which I'd be happy to accept as such. I could implement it in my code as `drop table if exists user_account_id_seq;
create sequence user_account_id_seq start with 1 increment by 10;`